# resuming AVAudio playback after moving between ViewControllers - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

in my project i have background music playing in my viewDidLoad, i also have another viewController and when i go to ViewController2 the audio pauses using the `[player pause];` method which is called in the viewWillDisappear. my problem is that when i move back to ViewController1, the audio starts over instead of resuming from where it stopped.
here's my code:

1) playMusic (called in ViewDidLoad):

```
-(void) playMusic{
NSError *error;
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:kSongTitle ofType:kSongFormat];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL error:&error];
[player setDelegate:self];
[player setNumberOfLoops:-1.0];
[player play];}
```

2) ViewWillDisappear:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
if (player.playing)
    [player pause];
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];}
```

3) resumeMusic (called in viewWillAppear):

```
-(void)resumeMusic{
if (!player){
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:kSongfullTitle];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError *err;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];
    if (err)
        NSLog(@"failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    else{
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"resuming");
    [player play];
} }
```

Comment: is player a property in the view controller? Is it defined with strong?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in viewController.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bit weird that player is nil, so first of all, make sure the player is defined with `strong`:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * player;
```

If this is the case, I would suggest a different angle. Since `ViewDidLoad` is called only once - when the viewController is allocated. If you reached there again, it means that the entire viewController was released and you can re-allocate `player` without fear (the audio will restart but you don't have a real choice)

So I suggest not hitting play in `ViewDidLoad` but only in `ViewWillAppear` (which is called each time - in the first time also)

So the code should be:

```
-(void) initPlayer  //called from ViewDidLoad
{
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:kSongTitle ofType:kSongFormat];
    NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL error:&error];
    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player setNumberOfLoops:-1.0];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [player play];
}
```

** OPTION 2: **

If you really want to have the audio ALWAYS resume from the point (no matter what) - and it really depends on what you are trying to do - move the `AVAudioPlayer` to a singleton (SharedInstance) and refrence it from wherever you need

Comment: I'm a bit new to whole programming world, could you tell how to create that shared instance?

Comment: http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/. Take into consideration it means your player lives throughout the life of the app, if that's what you intend, it's OK

Comment: But if the audio is relevant only to one screen - than what you are trying to do is "more correct" from the design perspective - so try what I suggested first

Comment: so do i have to call the playMusic method anywhere?

Comment: well... on option 1 - you still call it from ViewDidLoad. It is actually needs to be called initPlayer

Comment: well option 1 didn't help, i'm gonna try option 2, but the link you gave me doesn't work.

Comment: weird... anyway this tutorial is OK as well. https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=5VvfVKHDDZLxaOzMgLgL&url=http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes&ved=0CBoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHgKSLw-qHeKA58CRHZi7EetfX3tQ&sig2=4UJeQHxLiqe4ckeCpZveiQ

Comment: i fixed this problem by initialising the player in the AppDelegate, creating an appDelegate variable in ViewController1, calling [myAppDelegateVar.player play] in viewDidLoad, and calling [play] in viewWillAppear, and [pause] in viewWillDisappear.